# Migrating an entire ruby/rails set up from one machine to another

Tags: ruby, configuration, rubygems, migration, usb

Hello: I have a windows machine and a linux machine that both have the gems, ruby version, rails version, etc that I need. I want to copy the configuration for the Windows box to a couple of other windows boxes, and do the same for the Linux boxes (Ubuntu). I will move these to a studio whereby it won't have access to the internet during my stay.

I will install the same ruby version, and then I want ALL gems and configurations to be consistent and up to date across the board using the configs of the Linux and Window boxes as my guide. Can anyone advise how to do this if possible? For example, what folders/files would I need move, or can I simply copy and past the entire install of each config and paste them to the new boxes.

Thanks,
STS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [the Bundler](http://bundler.io/). It makes such tasks very easy. Just don't forget to reinstall bundle on the different system. Everything is kept, packages are specified in the Gemfile.
Just read docs, it's very intuitive to use.

Comment: I would not be able to download bundler. So are you saying that I copy all the files over to the targeted boxes, then install bundler from local?

Comment: You would need system or at least user install of Bundler on the target machine. In *nixes is just as easy as ```gem install --user bundler```. On Ubuntu there is a package available in your [standard repository](http://packages.ubunut.com/raring/bundler)

Comment: Ok. Let me try this out. Thanks